# web farm framework 2.0 - can I use WFF 2.0 with a hardware load balancer?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, load-balancing, web-farm

I have a web farm consisting of 2 web servers running Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7, load balanced between a hardware load balanacer. I'm reading about [WFF 2.0](http://www.iis.net/download/WebFarmFramework) and I don't know if it's possible to use it with a hardware load balancer. If so, how do I have to set it up.

Also, since I have a hardware load balancer can one of the web servers be the Controller and the Primary server?

Thanks...

Comment: did you manage to get WFF to work with a hardware load balancer, as I've also looked and cannot find any documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, no, don't try to use any cluster member as a Controller. That may become simple at some point in the future, but right now (WFF 2.1/2.2), don't do it.

See https://serverfault.com/a/248456/35088 .

For seconds, there's a script for use with F5 boxes:
http://blogs.iis.net/gursing/archive/2011/01/21/how-to-integrate-f5-with-web-farm-framework.aspx

Depending on your HLB, you might be able to rework it for your needs if it's not an F5.

Comment: (Semantic note: calling something "an HLB" is not helpful; it's a bit like saying "does this program work with Operating Systems?")

Comment: +1 for applying a bit of sound reason here.

Answer (score 0):

This ASP.net [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/20/microsoft-web-farm-framework-2-0.aspx) seems to say yes, it is possible. It seems like you have to do it with some [programming](http://blogs.iis.net/gursing/archive/2011/01/21/how-to-integrate-f5-with-web-farm-framework.aspx), however. I would recommend reaching out the manufacturer of the hardware load balancer, if you still have support, and ask them about it. Those who make it can tell you best.