# Microsoft Web Farm 2.0: How to install the Controller on the Primary Server?

Tags: web-farm

I install the Microsoft Web Farm 2.0 on a server, add that server and another server as primary and secondary, and everything is fine for a short time.  Then upon sync, it installs the Web Farm Server on the Secondary computer and fails the Web Farm Agent.  You should be able to disable installing the Web Farm Server on the Secondary.

Any ideas or links?

Specifically, Scott Guthrie mentioned "DemoController doesn’t technically need to be a separate machine – but makes it easier to understand the various roles in the walkthrough" [here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/08/introducing-the-microsoft-web-farm-framework.aspx)

EDIT:

Apparently, you need to enable file sharing in addition to sharing the folder.  It's a Vista/2008 thing.  You also need to put the network card in "private network" mode.  That gets things working, but doesn't explain how to control which apps are copied to secondary servers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Install the WFF on the Controller, not the Primary.

i.e.

ControllerComputer -> Controller
Server1 -> Primary
Server2 -> Secondary

Having the controller as an ARR router is expected. Having the controller *actually be* the Primary doesn't look like it was designed in.

Comment: "DemoController doesn’t technically need to be a separate machine – but makes it easier to understand the various roles in the walkthrough." from Scott Guthrie's http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/08/introducing-the-microsoft-web-farm-framework.aspx.  Hopefully he is correct, and we just need to find it.

Comment: There's no documentation on it because it's a complex scenario. The configuration you're synchronizing between the machines includes the configuration for the controller. You'd need to exclude this in order for the non-Controller to stay as a non-Controller, and that introduces fragility into the synchronization process. Add to that that ARR by default forwards all traffic to the target server, and requires reconfiguration to function on the same host as the application, and you're left with a world of reconfiguration, none of which is applicable to a secondary, which needs unique settings.

Comment: So how does one figure that out?

Comment: Start by working out which ARR rules are going to work for a same-server installation. If that much works, then ARR being duplicated between nodes becomes less problematic. Then, take a look at the interfaces exposed from the WFF, and see if there's a method of excluding WFF itself from being part of the configuration synchronization between the nodes. My answer reflects that this is not going to be trivial; my advice is to do it like the docs describe, to keep it relatively simple. Understand that's not what you're after here! :)